# AttributeError at /app/ 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, django, numpy-ndarray, face-recognition, web-development-server

I am making a wep app for face recognition by django and face_recogntion api, I don't how to solve this error

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .models import *
import face_recognition
import cv2
import urllib.request
import numpy as np
import dlib
def Home(request):
    print(f'request method is {request.method}')
    if(request.method=='GET'):
        return render(request, "app.html")
    elif(request.method=='POST'):
        print(f'printing req body {request.POST["imageURL"]}')
        imageURL = urllib.request.urlopen(request.POST["imageURL"])
        imageURL = face_recognition.load_image_file(imageURL)
        image = face_recognition.load_image_file(imageURL)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        imgLoc = face_recognition.face_locations(image);
        print(f'Image imagLoc {imgLoc}')
        cv2.imshow(image)
        cv2.waitKey(3000)
        return redirect('/app/')
```

I am asking question on stackoverflow for the first time so sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
imageURL = urllib.request.urlopen(request.POST["imageURL"])
imageURL = face_recognition.load_image_file(imageURL)
image = face_recognition.load_image_file(imageURL)
```

First

```
 imageURL = face_recognition.load_image_file(imageURL)
```

Now imageURL has `numpy.ndarray` type. Then

```
image = face_recognition.load_image_file(imageURL)
```

And here you are trying to load image once again passing that `numpy.ndarray` as an argument instead of passing image file path, i.e. string.
I don't understand why you are trying to load that image twice.